# How to overwrite a file in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a new file and overwrite the old file that's it. In simple words, every time I run my script it should overwrite Srv_Disk_Space.html file. I have tried giving `ForAppending, False` and `ForWriting, True`. Neither worked.

```
On Error Resume Next 
Const ForAppending = 8 
Const HARD_DISK = 3 
Const ForReading = 1 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

'Open the server list 
Set SrvList = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Servers.txt", ForReading) 

'Create a result file 
Set ReportFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Srv_Disk_Space.html", ForAppending, True)
```

Comment: If the answer to the linked question doesn't work for you please describe in more detail how *exactly* it "doesn't work". Removing `On Error Resume Next` from your code might help with that.

Comment: It worked but I don't know how to marka comment as an answer

Comment: You don't, and there's no need for it anyway. If you want to give credit: upvote the answer to the other question.

Comment: Okay Ansgar Thank you